# Puppet running exec before other commands

Tags: puppet

I am creating a group named `jboss` in puppet and then using exec to run a `sed` command to make some changes in `/etc/group` file afterwards.
The problem is that the exec command is running before the group command.

**My Yaml file**

```
    group { 'jboss':
        ensure => 'present',
        gid    => "501",
    }
    exec { "modify etc_group":
        command => "/bin/sed -i -e '<regex>' /etc/group",
        path    => "/bin:/usr/bin",
        unless  => "<condition>",
    }
```

**Puppet run output**

```
notice: /Stage[main]/App::Misc/Exec[modify etc_group]/returns: current_value notrun, should be 0 (noop)
notice: /Stage[main]/App::Misc/Group[jboss]/ensure: current_value absent, should be present (noop)
```

How to make sure that the `exec` runs after the `group` command?

Comment: Abusing `exec` to manage a resource (e.g. the `groups` file) in different ways is almost always a Bad Idea. It might be a better question how to circumvent the need.

Comment: Yes, I know it's a bad way but unfortunately due toa  bad legacy design we have to modify this file manually and can't get around it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply just define relationship between `group` and `exec`.

E.g:

```
exec { "modify etc_group":
    command => "/bin/sed -i -e '<regex>' /etc/group",
    path    => "/bin:/usr/bin",
    unless  => "<condition>",
    require => Group['jboss'],
}
```

More about relationships in puppet [here](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_relationships.html#syntax-relationship-metaparameters).